# How do I handle an error ''list index out of range" as an exception?

Tags: python-3.x, list, exception

The thing is , that I am given some code and it is structured this way that we expect some accesses to not - initialised elements in the list. (I don't want to change the logic behind it, because it deals with some math concepts ). But I've been given the code in some other language and I want to do the same with python (handling this exception and let the program run).

```
a = []
for i in range(1,10,2): a.append(i)
for j in range(10):
    try:
        a[i] +=1
    finally:
        a.append(1)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-edc940b2697a> in <module>
      3 for j in range(10):
      4     try:
----> 5         a[i] +=1
      6     finally:
      7         a.append(1)

IndexError: list index out of range
```

I then tried something else (after reading a similar stack overflow post)

```
a = []
for i in range(1,10,2): a.append(i)
for j in range(10):
    
    if(a[j]): a[j] +=1
    else:
        a.append(1)
ndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-324628aa850d> in <module>
      3 for j in range(10):
      4 
----> 5     if(a[j]): a[j] +=1
      6     else:
      7         a.append(1)

IndexError: list index out of range
```

As you can see the error , persisted.

Comment: Check the length of the list after the first `for` loop

Comment: In your first example, replace `a[i] += 1` to `a[j] += 1` on line 5.
The error in your second example is a different error. You can't do `if(a[j])`, because if `a[j]` does not exist, then an `IndexError` will be raised

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can handle it with:

```
except IndexError:
    pass
```

full code:

```
a = []
for i in range(1, 10, 2): a.append(i)
for j in range(10):
    try:
        a[i] += 1
    except IndexError:
        pass
    finally:
        a.append(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a = []
for i in range(1,10,2):
    a.append(i)
    try:
        for j in range(10):
            a[i] +=1
    except:
        pass
    finally:
        a.append(1)
print(a)
```